# AWS MSK > Lambda Event Source Mapping

Tags: debugging, logging, lambda, aws-msk

I've successfully created an Event Source Mapping (ESM) Trigger on my lambda function to my MSK cluster. For awhile it was polling and reading events from my kafka topic without issue. Recently though, I noticed that it has suddenly stopped. I verified that the topic has a large volume of new records, and my batch size is 100, so I don't see why it would have stopped triggering the lambda function. There are no Lambda logs and invocations shows that the lambda is *not* being invoked at all (so no logs makes sense) The MSK Trigger as well says that it is in a health state and indicates no errors. It just doesn't run.

Does anyone have advice on debugging the ESM trigger between lambda and MSK cluster since I believe I've verified that the kafka topic is behaving as expected, and the lambda isn't ever running.

Usually I would post code but this is an AWS configuration and I'm just looking for info on how to further debug the ESM, so I have not provided any as I don't see what would be relevant.

Comment: Did you try to disable and enable the trigger? Cloud any other settings change on a cluster?

Comment: due to restrictions I wasn't able to just turn it on and off through the UI but what you suggested is correct. I destroyed it and recreated it (with the same consumer group ID) and after that it worked without issue. If you want to add a "did you try turning it off and on again" answer, I will mark it as correct since it seems that may be the best option when there is no logs/metrics to go by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuck triggers can be fixed with two options:

1. Disable/Enable trigger using [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html#SSS-UpdateEventSourceMapping-request-Enabled) or any other way
2. [Delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_DeleteEventSourceMapping.html) + [Create](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html) trigger